# France-educated or French-educated

Tags: word-choice, differences, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

If a renowned scholar was born, let's say, in Japan, and he/she receives a Nobel Prize thanks to a dissertation he/she wrote in France after studying there for a master's degree and a doctor's degree, do you use "France-educated scholar" or "French-educated scholar"?

He received a full education up to a bachelor's degree in Japan.

My gut feeling indicates both of them are fine (I would go for French-educated, though), is there any distinction you can be sure of between them?

Comment: If I google "France educated" I get about 6,000 hits and if I read them, most  are not used adjectivally except by a few non-native writers.  https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22France+educated%22  If you are getting 64 million then I think there is a problem with your computer.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK *Quotation marks*. I edited the question. The number keeps changing.

Comment: In any case, you should be googling, "France-educated" not "France educated".  Otherwise you aren't searching for the adjectival form - merely the two words together.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: Because people are always honor-bound to hyphenate compound adjectives on the Internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching Google and hoping to get a sensible numerical comparison is a complete waste of time. I suggest you search a corpus of published works. Example:

Google ngram: [France-educated,French-educated](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=France-educated%2CFrench-educated&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CFrench%20-%20educated%3B%2Cc0)

Note that you need the adjectival form so the hyphen is mandatory.

Follow that link and you will see that there is not a single instance of 'France-educated'.

Comment: My computer must be mal-functioning.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the ambiguity of both your expressions, I would write *Born in Japan, educated in France.*

Clarity is almost always more important than shorthand.

Comment: So... Japan-born or Japanese-born?

Comment: @GEdgar:  Both are more awkward than *born in Japan*.  However, *Japanese-born* implies that one is born to Japanese parents; *Japan-born* conveys the intended meaning, but it is an uncommon figure of speech.

Answer (score 0):

Both terms are clumsy and should be avoided.

The location where the scholar was raised or trained is irrelevant to the topic of the dissertation for which a Nobel prize was awarded. The name of his degrees and the institution where they were pursued is more relevant than the country of those institutions

If the scholar's national origin is worth mentioning, then it is worth constructing a full sentence be clear and precise.